# Does sharpbox use dropbox syc or datastore apis

Tags: dropbox-api, sharpbox

Dropbox today announced the deprecation of the sync and data store apis

https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2015/04/deprecating-the-sync-and-datastore-apis/#disqus_thread

Does anyone know if the sharpbox library uses these and will be affected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the [SharpBox](https://sharpbox.codeplex.com/) library uses the Dropbox Core API, not the Dropbox Sync SDK or Datastore API, and so it should not be affected.

Comment: My fiddler traces confirm sharpbox is creating traffic to api.dropbox.com which is the core api. Thanks!

Comment: Will accept the answer as soon as stackoverflow lets me

Comment: BTW, the Sync API (really an SDK) also uses the same endpoints on api.dropbox.com, and the Datastore API is also on api.dropbox.com. So checking the domain doesn't really help. :-) That said, SharpBox isn't the Sync SDK, so it's safe on that front, and it doesn't support the Datastore API.